# Beautiful Soup Not Getting NBA.com Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the data from the table on this webpage: http://stats.nba.com/league/team/#!/advanced/ . Unfortunately, the following code does not give me anything because the soup (see below) contains no "td"s, even though there are many "td"s to be found when inspecting the webpage.

On the other hand, running the same code for the website "http://espn.go.com/nba/statistics/team/_/stat/offense-per-game" does give me what I want.

Why does the code work for one site and not the other, and is there anything I can do to get the data I want from the first site?

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="http://stats.nba.com/league/team/#!/advanced/"
r=requests.get(url)
soupNBAadv=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

tds=soupNBAadv.find_all("td")
for i in tds:
    print i.text
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `BeautifulSoup` here at all. The table you see in the browser is formed with the help of an *additional get request* to an endpoint which *returns a JSON response*, simulate it:

```
import requests

url = "http://stats.nba.com/league/team/#!/advanced/"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = headers
    session.get(url, headers=headers)

    params = {
        'DateFrom': '',
        'DateTo': '',
        'GameScope': '',
        'GameSegment': '',
        'LastNGames': '0',
        'LeagueID': '00',
        'Location': '',
        'MeasureType': 'Advanced',
        'Month': '0',
        'OpponentTeamID': '0',
        'Outcome': '',
        'PaceAdjust': 'N',
        'PerMode': 'Totals',
        'Period': '0',
        'PlayerExperience': '',
        'PlayerPosition': '',
        'PlusMinus': 'N',
        'Rank': 'N',
        'Season': '2014-15',
        'SeasonSegment': '',
        'SeasonType': 'Regular Season',
        'StarterBench': '',
        'VsConference': '',
        'VsDivision': ''
    }

    response = session.get('http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats', params=params)
    results = response.json()
    headers = results['resultSets'][0]['headers']
    rows = results['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']
    for row in rows:
        print(dict(zip(headers, row)))
```

Prints:

```
{u'MIN': 2074.0, u'TEAM_ID': 1610612737, u'TEAM_NAME': u'Atlanta Hawks', u'AST_PCT': 0.687, u'CFPARAMS': u'Atlanta Hawks', u'EFG_PCT': 0.531, u'DEF_RATING': 99.4, u'NET_RATING': 7.5, u'PIE': 0.556, u'AST_TO': 1.81, u'TS_PCT': 0.57, u'GP': 43, u'L': 8, u'OREB_PCT': 0.21, u'REB_PCT': 0.488, u'W': 35, u'W_PCT': 0.814, u'DREB_PCT': 0.743, u'CFID': 10, u'PACE': 96.17, u'TM_TOV_PCT': 0.149, u'AST_RATIO': 19.9, u'OFF_RATING': 106.9}
{u'MIN': 1897.0, u'TEAM_ID': 1610612738, u'TEAM_NAME': u'Boston Celtics', u'AST_PCT': 0.635, u'CFPARAMS': u'Boston Celtics', u'EFG_PCT': 0.494, u'DEF_RATING': 104.0, u'NET_RATING': -2.7, u'PIE': 0.489, u'AST_TO': 1.73, u'TS_PCT': 0.527, u'GP': 39, u'L': 26, u'OREB_PCT': 0.245, u'REB_PCT': 0.496, u'W': 13, u'W_PCT': 0.333, u'DREB_PCT': 0.747, u'CFID': 10, u'PACE': 99.12, u'TM_TOV_PCT': 0.145, u'AST_RATIO': 18.5, u'OFF_RATING': 101.3}
...
```

---

[Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/)-based solution:

```
from pprint import pprint
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://stats.nba.com/league/team/#!/advanced/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

# wait for the table to load
table = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'table-responsive')))

stats = []
headers = [th.text for th in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('th')]
for tr in table.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr[@data-ng-repeat]'):
    cells = [td.text for td in tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')]

    stats.append(dict(zip(headers, cells)))

pprint(stats)

driver.quit()
```

Prints:

```
[{u'AST Ratio': u'19.8',
  u'AST%': u'68.1',
  u'AST/TO': u'1.84',
  u'DREB%': u'74.3',
  u'DefRtg': u'100.2',
  u'GP': u'51',
  u'MIN': u'2458',
  u'NetRtg': u'7.4',
  u'OREB%': u'21.0',
  u'OffRtg': u'107.7',
  u'PACE': u'96.12',
  u'PIE': u'55.3',
  u'REB%': u'48.8',
  u'TO Ratio': u'14.6',
  u'TS%': u'57.2',
  u'Team': u'Atlanta Hawks',
  u'eFG%': u'53.4'},
  ...
 {u'AST Ratio': u'18.6',
  u'AST%': u'62.8',
  u'AST/TO': u'1.65',
  u'DREB%': u'77.8',
  u'DefRtg': u'100.2',
  u'GP': u'52',
  u'MIN': u'2526',
  u'NetRtg': u'3.5',
  u'OREB%': u'24.9',
  u'OffRtg': u'103.7',
  u'PACE': u'95.75',
  u'PIE': u'53.4',
  u'REB%': u'51.8',
  u'TO Ratio': u'15.4',
  u'TS%': u'54.4',
  u'Team': u'Washington Wizards',
  u'eFG%': u'50.9'}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this. I'm still a bit confused though. The code you've written prints out more than just what is on http://stats.nba.com/league/team/#!/advanced/ -- why is this? Also, by replacing "advanced" with "misc" both in the url and in the 'MeasureType' gives something similar to what is on the Misc url, but, perhaps because of the 'PerMode': 'Totals' parameter, the data on the Misc url does not get printed out as per game averages. I suppose my general question is then: how is your code controlling which data is printed and how it is printed?

Comment: @JBL well, the approach I've proposed is kind of a low-level one - you basically try to mimic what the javascript code is doing on the browser-side, the requests made to get the data which would later be used to form the HTML table. Another approach would be to stay on a high-level and automate a real browser with `selenium` - would be okay with this solution? If yes, I can provide you with something you can start with. Thanks.

Comment: @ alecxe, yes I would be interested in learning how selenium could help with this.

Comment: Regarding your previous solution, how did you determine which of the many browser's _get request_ s is the one that is used to form the HTML table?

Comment: @JBL updated the answer with a selenium-based solution. Which request was responsible for filling table data - I've filtered XHR requests only - there were a few and wasn't difficult to choose the correct one. I don't think there is anything else to add to the answer. Consider closing this topic by accepting the answer - if you have more questions - consider creating a separate SO question. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The reason behind not getting the data from the first url using `requests.get()` is, the data is fetched from the server using an ajax call. And the ajax call url is `http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashteamstats`. You have to pass some parameters with it.

When making a `requests.get()` call you will only get those data that show in the page source of your browser. In your browser press `ctrl+u` to see the page source and you can see that, there is no data in the source.

In chrome browser use the developer tools and see in the `Network` tab what requests the page is making. In firefox you can use `firebug` and see in `Net` tab.

In case of second url the page source is populated with data(View page source to examine). So you can get it by making the a get request in that specific url.

alecxe's answer demonstrate how to get data from the first url.