# NBA.com Tracking Stats using python?

Tags: javascript, python, database, web-scraping

Could anybody give me some help in my attempt to pull down the NBA.com "tracking" stats using a python script into a simple table?  This would be an example of the area of stats from the site i'm having trouble with.

http://stats.nba.com/tracking/#!/player/defense/

NBA.com makes it a bit difficult to get direct access to their stats, instead opting to make it, i think, a java formatted table that won't all show at once.  Somebody asked a similar question and was given a decent python example code for a section of nba.com stats, the team advanced stats, and the table itself isn't very clean.  It's pretty easy to alter to grab most of the code give in that to get other stats from the site, however, the "tracking" ones, which are new, i'm unable to determine the right query. The other answer is shown in the following link.

[Beautiful Soup Not Getting NBA.com Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28081941/beautiful-soup-not-getting-nba-com-data)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://stats.nba.com/js/data/sportvu/2014/defenseData.json
http://stats.nba.com/js/data/sportvu/2014/catchShootData.json
http://stats.nba.com/js/data/sportvu/2014/drivesData.json

... and so on. Use Chrome developer tools to the the URL's. Look in the network tab, filtering by XHR makes it easier to spot usually.